# how to exclude files from loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the next config for webpack loaders:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: rootDir + '/src',
      loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions'
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
      loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]'
    }]
  }
```

I want to exclude some files from autoprefixer loader. How can I do this?
If I do like this:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: 'someFile',
  loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions'
}
```

someFile will be excluded not only from autoprefixer loader, it will be excluded from styles, css and autoprefixer loader, but I need exclude file only from autoprefixer loader. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Create two loader configurations, one for 'somefile', and one for the rest of your CSS files that excludes 'somefile':

```
module: {
  loaders: [
  ...
  {
    test: 'somefile',
    loader: 'style!css'
  }, {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions',
    exclude: 'somefile'
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I already did as you wrote. Anyway thanks a lot!