# regular expression except pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

Lets say I have multiple css files.

```
bear.css
cat.css
styles.css
colors.css
... multiptle different css files
```

I would like to select all the files except the bear.css and cat.css
Look around operation might be work but I could not make it work

Condition is like if((pattern != bear.css && pattern != cat.css) && .css))

I need to add the regex to   test: /.css$/, which is webpack css loader config

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873317/how-to-exclude-files-from-loader

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!bear|cat).*\.css$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnvecP/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?!bear|cat)` - negative lookahead to make sure that whatever follows the current position should neither be `bear` nor `cat`
- `.*` - once the above condition is satisfied, we match 0+ occurrences of any character except the newline character
- `\.css` - matches `.css`
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Comment: Okay. Then please unselect it as the answer as I provided the javascript regex. If I find a compatible solution, I will update my answer.

Comment: Got an upvote from me because I went to regex101, wondering as always why people use it when it doesn't even support replacing....And then saw the substitution tab at the bottom for the first time :)

Comment: ^(?!bear|cat).* that one can include other files if there is other files

Comment: @user3882878 Did you escape \ by adding another \ in front of it in the regex?

Comment: Yes i did add  \